# Terraform Destroy Error when connected to TFE

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-enterprise

I have  created a workspace in Terraform Enterprise by running a terraform init && terraform plan locally with Terraform enterprise set up as my back end:

```
    # Using a single workspace:
    terraform {
     backend "remote" {
      hostname = "dep.app.example.io"
      organization = "nnnn"

      workspaces {
       name = "create-workspace"
      }
     }
    }
```

Terraform Apply works, and I can launch an ec2 via Terraform Enterprise with this code:

```
    provider "aws" {
     region = "${var.region}"
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "feature" {
     count = 1
     ami = "${var.ami}"
     availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone}"
     instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
     tags = {
      Name = "${var.name_tag}"
     }
    }
```

Now when I run a terraform destroy, I get this error:

```
    Error: error creating run: Invalid Attribute Infrastructure is 
    not destroyable

    The configured "remote" backend encountered an unexpected 
    error. Sometimes this is caused by network connection problems, 
    in which case you could retry the command. If the issue 
    persists please open a support ticket to get help resolving the 
    problem.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want to be able to run a terraform destroy that destroys the infrastructure my new Terraform enterprise workspace spins up.

EDIT: LOGS:

```
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.11.11  ac4fff416318bf0915a0ab80e062a99ef3724334
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.11.1
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/usr/local/bin/terraform", "destroy"}
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /Users/nlegorrec/.terraformrc
2019/04/03 09:11:54 Loading CLI configuration from /Users/nlegorrec/.terraformrc
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"destroy"}
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "f7abdc54-236c-c906-e701-049f3e2cc00c"
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "f7abdc54-236c-c906-e701-049f3e2cc00c"
2019/04/03 09:11:54 [DEBUG] Service discovery for dep.app.redbull.com at https://dep.app.redbull.com/.well-known/terraform.json
2019/04/03 09:11:56 [DEBUG] Retrieve version constraints for service tfe.v2 and product terraform
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [INFO] command: backend initialized: *remote.Remote
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/usr/local/bin"
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-aws_v2.4.0_x4"
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "aws", "2.4.0", "/Users/nlegorrec/dev/Software Engineering/emp-kpi-tracker_web/dep/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.4.0_x4"
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/local/bin"
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2019/04/03 09:11:57 [INFO] backend/remote: starting Apply operation

2019/04/03 09:12:00 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
Error: error creating run: Invalid Attribute Infrastructure is not destroyable

The configured "remote" backend encountered an unexpected error. Sometimes
this is caused by network connection problems, in which case you could retry
the command. If the issue persists please open a support ticket to get help
resolving the problem.
```

Comment: Can you enable logging and share the logs while running terraform destroy?

Comment: @SushantSonker Added logs.

Comment: My apologies for the late response since I was travelling. I am not sure how you are referencing the backend in your modules, but you can try re-initializing your backend with terraform init as below and then try running the terraform destroy. ````terraform init \
    -backend-config="address=demo.consul.io" \
    -backend-config="path=example_app/terraform_state" \
    -backend-config="scheme=https"````

Comment: @NickLeGorrec Does my answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though its a bit late hopefully this answer can help others in the future.

When using Terraform Enterprise or Terraform Cloud, you need to ensure that you are following their guidance on ***Destruction and Deletion*** from within the ***Workspace***

Documentation for this is located [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/workspaces/settings.html#destruction-and-deletion)

To queue the destruction of infrastructure that is managed by a workspace you need to ensure that within the ***Variables*** of the workspace that you have assigned a variable with the name `CONFIRM_DESTROY` with a value of `1`

***Importantly, any changes to the workspace require admin privleges***

Once you have completed that you should be able to use the CLI Workflow as you would locally in Terraform.